# Conditional styled-components in object notation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, jss

Styled components documentation doesn't mention this case and I can't figure out the syntax.

How would I turn this styled component:

```js
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  color: red;
  ${props => props.disabled && css`
    color: grey;
    background-color: grey;
  `}
`
```

into object notation:

```js
const StyledButton = styled.button(props => ({
  color: 'red',
  ------
}))
```

I know the following would solve this question, but for my use case I need to keep the logic from the first exemple. So this won't make it for me:

```js
const StyledButton = styled.button(props => ({
  color: props.disabled ? 'grey' : 'red',
  backgroundColor: props.disabled ? 'grey' : transparent,
}))
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: You're asking to do something and the question reads as if you've done exactly what you're asking. What's the problem?

Comment: I need to keep the disabled part in a separate block like on the first exemple. The last exemple is a way it could be done for this exemple, but won't solve my real use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would be what you're after (or similar)

```
const StyledButton = styled.button((props) => {
  const disabledStyles =  {
    color: 'grey',
    'background-color': 'grey',
  };

  return {
    color: 'red',
    ...(props.disabled && disabledStyles)
  };
})
```

I definitely don't understand why you can't use the ternary approach you have above but I've had some weird reqs on projects too. Good luck

Comment: You are the best! That was exactly what I needed. Thanks 